# Accessing the positional arguments in $@

Tags: bash

I have 2 functions

```
script1:

func_1(){
   func_2 "one" "two" "three" "fourth argument"
}

script 2:
func_2(){
   some_method_call -arg1 $1 -arg2 "$2$3" -arg3 "$4"
}
```

here $4 is taken as "fourth" instead of "fourth argument"

I have tried using $@ but that helps in only printing the arguments but how do I access the *$4* entirely.

Comment: How do you know that `$4` is just `fourth`? How is `some_method_call` parsing its arguments?

Comment: The issue is when I do a echo "$4" in func_2 it prints saying "fourth" instead of "fourth argument". So the some_method_call isnt getting the proper arguments.

I tried something like this

for i in "$@" ;
 do
   first_arg=$1
   second_arg=$2
   third_arg=$3
   fourth_arg=$4
done

But this isnt a proper solution because fourth_arg was still "fourth"

Comment: This works as written (assuming both functions get defined in the same context). Try defining `some_method_call() { echo "Got $# arguments:"; for arg in "$@"; do printf "  '%s'\n" "$arg"; done; }`, then run `func_1` and see what it prints. The actual problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: These scripts aren't calling each other, and each script individually will not do anything when executed. Please include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clarify how they call each other.

Comment: Apologies the example isnt complete.
What I meant was that the func_2 is called by func_1 but the arguments that some_method_call receives isnt complete because of the spaces in betweem

Comment: You need to show what `some_method_call` looks like, because there is nothing wrong with either function shown. (Well, `$1` should be quoted, but that won't affect the value of `$4`.)

Comment: your functions are ok. Add `echo "4=$4"` before `some-method-call` to verify it.

Comment: You would only get the symptom you describe if you fail to quote the argument when you *call* "func_2". Your code as you show it is OK. Did you retype it here or did you cut and paste from your real code?